# Encrypt and Decrypt is possible for apple watch response data?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, encryption, apple-watch

I am working on e-commerce application and implementing for apple watch also.
The requirement is encrypt and decrypt the data which is sending from watchkit extension to iPhone appdelegate class vice versa.

Here in watchkit interface class openParentApplication method is sending to iPhone class a dictionary and catching reply from iPhone class also a dictionary. So is it possible to do encryption and decryption for apple watch request and response data?

watchkit interface method:

```
WKInterfaceController.openParentApplication(requestData as [NSObject : AnyObject], reply: { (reply, error) -> Void in
```

iPhone appdelegate method:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleWatchKitExtensionRequest:(NSDictionary *)userInfo reply:(void (^)(NSDictionary *))reply
```

Comment: You realise that the data is being sent from your phone... ...to your phone, right?

Comment: yes sending to phone and getting from phone right? @Schemetrical

Comment: There is little need to encrypt.